# Unknown column type when generating schema

Tags: exception, doctrine, symfony, dbal

I am developing an application using Symfony2 and Doctrine, the problem comes when
I try to create tables for Role and User Entities using `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`, the relation is ManyToMany and although the mapping information, the annotations, seem to be correct it throws the following exception:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException] Unknown column type role requested

What can I do? Thank you very much.

Comment: There is a `--verbose` option to the symfony2 CLI. Does it display more information? And of course, you should post annotations.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a annotation like this:

```
/**
 * @Column(type="role")
 */
 protected $role;
```

This is a problem, because Doctrine doesn't know of any type named `role`.

I have to say that this is an assumption because you haven't posted any code...

Comment: The problem is I have got no @Column(type="role") al column types are known types.

Comment: As stated before, you should post your annotations, I don't think anyone can help without actual code...